# div wrapper for submit button

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, submit

I have a simple login form:

```
<form action="/users/login" class="form-inline" id="UserLoginForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
    </div>
    <input name="data[User][email]" class="input-small" placeholder="E-mail" maxlength="50" type="text" id="UserEmail"/>
    <input name="data[User][password]" class="input-small" placeholder="Password" type="password" id="UserPassword"/>
    <button class='btn' type='submit'>Login</button>
</form>
```

It is using bootstrap for styling. As for js jquery and AngularJS is loaded.

My issue is, when I display this form my submit button goes to the next line. If I inspect dom I see an `<div class="actions">...</div>` wrapper around my submit button. This does not happen if I omit `type='submit'` part from the form definition.

My question who is adding this wrapper and how can I avoid it.

Comment: Given you've tagged this with twitter-bootstrap, you might want to start looking there...

Comment: bootstrap.css contains: .form-actions {}
.form-actions:before,
.form-actions:after {}
 it also has .block-level-inputs, which obviously forces display:block.  class "actions" has to come from something else.

Comment: what happens if you change the div to a span?

Answer (score 1):

If you see the examples of Twitter Bootstrap, I can see they are using two classes for `form-inline` example. [Please check this.](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons) fro different types and form with buttons. Try applying `well` class along with it.

```
<form class="well form-inline">
  <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It is still happening. I think it is caused by another javascript I include.